# The term "Fathered" but in a negative/absent way that does not insult the child

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Directly below is the excerpt from my novel. I cannot think of a single word, or even a short phrase, that would insult him without insulting the child as well.

*"He fathered - no, scratch that - he {BLANK}ed a illegitimate child whom I've felt the moral obligation to help raise in his absence."*

I want to avoid using the word 'spawned' due to its negative connotation.

Comment: begot (very biblical too)

Comment: The insult to the child isn't in its manner of parentage, it's the fact that the character raises it only out of a feeling of obligation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best word for you to use is "begat," a very Biblical word which means "to father or mother" but only in a strictly biological sense. From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/beget#English).

> To beget (v). To father; to sire; to produce (a child). To bring forth.